# How to use DvbSiparser.h to parser mpeg2 TS in vc++?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, directshow, mpeg2-ts, dvb

I have a Mpeg2 TS should be analyze. I m using a header file introduced in Windows Kit ver 8 (or 8.1) named **Dvbsiparser.h.** 
I know (but not sure) I should build a filter graph and then add tow important filter: 
1. Mpeg2 Sections and table    2. Mpeg2 Transport Information
After then, I use a IDvbSiParser obj to analyze stream.
When I want to instantiate IDvbSiParser:

> CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(IDvbSiParser), ..., ..., IID_IDvbSiParser,
>   ...)

I get Link error: Unresolved external IID_IDvbSiParser.

I use Visual stdio 2013, .Net 4.5 and msvc++.
I also included stream.h and link winmm.lib, strmbased.lib, msvcrtd.lib and strmiids.lib and set true lib path to windows kit.
All other objects are created except IDvbSiParser.

Should I use another lib or include another header file?
How can I find proper lib for IID_IDvbSiParser?
Thanks.

Comment: replace `IID_IDvbSiParser` with `__uuidof(IDvbSiParser)`

Comment: I tried this solution, but I did not get result OK (i.e S_OK). Is there another problem or I must use IID_IDvbSiParser?

Comment: The first arguments is unlikely to be correct. I am not sure where you get this code from and why this value exactly is present there. You need a valid class identifier, typical notation is CLSID_Something. Possibly, `CLSID_DvbSiParser`.

Comment: About using CLSID_Something, you are right, but I could not find any header file including valid CLSID and IID for IDvbSiParser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all I read [MSDN about DvbSiParser2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743037(v=vs.85).aspx) again and faced this important note:

> The IDvbSiParser2 interface inherits from IDvbSiParser. IDvbSiParser2
>   also has these types of members:

So, we can use IDvbSiParser2 instead of IDvbSiParser, Because we have know have proper and true CLSID for IDvbSiParser have mentioned in [IDvbSiParser2 MSDN Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743037(v=vs.85).aspx).
Next step including defining new GUID variable like this:

```
GUID CLSID_IDvbSiParser2 = {0xF6B96EDA, 0x1A94, 0x4476, 0xA8, 0x5F, 0X4D, 0x3D, 0xC7, 0xB3, 0x9C, 0x3F};
IDvbSiParser2 *ppdvbsp;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_IDvbSiParser2, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IDvbSiParser2), void **( pDvbsiparser ));
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) { lab lab lab};
```

I think you will get S_OK as I did.